# Laravel model returns "Undefined property: stdClass::$name"

Tags: php, laravel, model

I keep trying to get my class model to work but it keeps returning this error.
The model looks like:

```
class Food
{
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $results = DB::select('select * from food where id = ?', array($id));
        if ( empty($results) )
        {
            throw new Exception('Food do not exsist.');
        } else {
            $this->food = (object) $results;
        }
    }

    public function name()
    {
        return $this->food->name;
    }

}
```

And when I call it:

```
$food = new Food($id);
var_dump($food->name()); exit;
```

Returns:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$name
```

Answer (score 4):

Base on your code, `DB::select` will return an array which contains several objects (may be more than one), and then you assign it to `$this->food`.

Remember, the `$this->food` looks like

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => 'Beef'
    )
)
```

Actually, `$this->food->name` is trying to access an undefined property.

**Solution 1**:

You should use `$this->food[0]->name` to access it.

Although it looks weird, but it works.

**Solution 2**:

Why not call `Food::find($id)` to fetch the object instead of `$food = new food($id)`

You can learn more by reading this http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent