# Can't Access data from Many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, model, many-to-many

I have Bus and Route model trying to access route through bus but gets error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$route

Controller:

```
foreach ($Bus as $tBus){

            foreach ($tBus->route as $tBusRoute) {//Undefined property: stdClass::$route
                if($tBusRoute->id == $rId){
                    $BusRouteId = $tBusRoute->pivot->id;            }
            }
            }
```

Bus Model:

```
class Bus extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'bus';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamp = true;


    public function route(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Route::class , 'bus_route' , 'bus_id' , 'route_id')->withPivot('id');
}
```

Route Model:

```
class Route extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'route';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamp = true;

    public function bus(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Bus::class , 'bus_route' , 'route_id' , 'bus_id');
    }
```

Error: Undefined property: stdClass::$route

Comment: how did you get the `$Bus` var?   seems like you used Query Builder directly instead of Eloquent

Comment: $Bus = DB::table('bus')->where('transport_company_id',$tId)->get(); i used this

Comment: @Usuma Khan .. yes, that's the reason.. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417312/laravel-model-returns-undefined-property-stdclassname)

Comment: So instead of DB query, use the Model approach like this: $Bus = Bus::where('transport_company_id',$tId)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Query Builder directly and not going through Eloquent to do your query.

To use the model:

```
$buses = Bus::where('transport_company_id', $tld)->get();
```

The Query Builder returns a Collection of `stdClass` objects, hence your error. If you query through the Model you will get a Collection of Model instances.

[Laravel 6.0 Docs - Eloquent - Retrieving Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: no problem, and as mentioned in other answers, you will want to eager load the relationship for efficiency. `Bus::with('route')->.....`

Answer (score 0):

Better to Use Eloquent with relationship.

`$buses = Bus::with('route')->where('transport_company_id',$tId)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/queries) instead of [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), so your objects will not be casted to models. Try this instead:

```
$buses = Bus::where('transport_company_id', $tld)->get();
```

Then, you are looping through the `$buses` collection and calling the relationship, so I suggest you to [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) this values to avoid the [N+1 problem](https://vegibit.com/how-to-fix-the-n1-problem/):

```
$buses = Bus::with('route')->where('transport_company_id', $tld)->get();
```

> PS: Given the fact that a `Bus` may have many `Route`s you should
>   rename your relationship to plural: `routes`

Third, you can compare your results like this:

```
$buses = Bus::with('route')->where('transport_company_id', $tld)->get();

foreach($buses as $bus)
{
    foreach($bus->route as $route)
    {
        // now you can get the $route instance with the pivot data:
        dd($route->pivot->a_pivot_field);
    }
}
```